# How can I improve my Freq to Voltage circuit?

Tags: troubleshooting, frequency-measurement, circuit-analysis

I had a term project which was based around Analog-to-Digital convertors.
We used an[LM2907 Freq-toVoltage](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snas555b/snas555b.pdf) convertor to take a 150mVpp sine wave (0- 1kHz) and convert that to a voltage.  The voltage was sent to a PIC 18F4685 mcu that ran on a Northmicro101 proto board and through some embedded code would take the anaolg voltage and convert it to a 10bit value.  This value was translated back to a frequency value and displayed on the LCD.

It wasn't meant to be a bullet proof set-up, more about learning and implimenting the concepts learned through the term.  However what we found was that the frequency on the LCD would creep upwards 1 or 2 Hz after about 15-20 minutes and would keep on doing a very slow creep the longer we ran the circuit.

My question is what would be the most likely cause for this creep and how would we eliminate it in a future version?

The F2V circuit was tied to the NM101 protoboards +9V power supply and the output of the F2V circuit was set for +5V output max for PIC input pin protection.

[image]

Comment: What is the signal source you are measuring? Is it guaranteed to output a correct frequency with less than 1-2 Hz drift?

Comment: I hadn't thought about that.  The function generator was a HP 33120A so I figured it should be the most stable part of the whole system.  I'll do a search for the specs.

Comment: That instrument should be accurate to something like 50 ppm (depending on the options you bought with it) and drift only a few ppm per year. I don't think that is  the problem, unless it has sustained some damage over the years (an HP nameplate means it's more than 10 years old).

Comment: School equipment, been around for at least 10 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect a big part of the drift you're seeing is related to this equation in the LM2907 datasheet:

[image]

This shows that the LM2907 output voltage will drift linearly if your Vcc drifts. If you are not using an extremely good regulator to power the LM2907, this could easily account for 0.2% of drift.

<strike>If you are using a precision reference circuit for your ADC (or a bandgap reference internal to the uC), you might try switching to using Vcc as the reference. With a Vcc-referenced ADC any affect of Vcc drift on the LM2907 output will be compensated by the drift in the ADC operation.</strike>

Edit: I remove the prior advice because I see you are powering the LM2907 from 9 V, while the PIC is powered from 5 V; therefore, you can't expect the two power supplies to drift equally.

Comment: The PIC is powered via a 5V regulator on the Northmicro board.  The Northmicro board is powered by a 9V-dc power supply which regulates down to 5V for the PIC.

Comment: @ChefFlambe, If you have a good multimeter, watch the voltage of the 9-V supply where it connects to the LM2907. If you see it drifting up by 10 mV or more as your freq reading changes, I think you found your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider all possible sources of drift; any term in the equation from Photon's answer is a possibility, plus (potentially) the temperature of the chip itself.

the Photon pointed at probably the chief culprit : the 9V supply. However, the values of R1 and C1 may change with temperature, and so may the "constant" K as the LM2907 temperature changes. Diagnosing temperature drift is easier WITHOUT a simulator : touch the suspect components with a warm finger while watching the output. (Follow ESD precautions, and on vacuum tube or other HV equipment be careful!).

Hairdriers or freezer spray are also useful, but a scatter gun approach. If the circuit is stable in the face of such abuse, look elsewhere, but they won't pinpoint a single component.

It's likely you find more than one culprit; though hopefully you will find one main offender and fixing it will be "good enough".

Capacitors vary in their thermal stability : Z5U ceramics are terrible; some other ceramics are much better; polystyrene foil caps are very good, for the longest time, silver mica capacitors were highly prized as the best choice for frequency stable circuits.

Resistors also vary but not so much; there are metal film precision resistors with 10ppm/K temperature stability if that's the culprit.

If the chip itself is temperature sensitive, there are a variety of possibilities such as building temperature dependence into its power supply, or cancelling out the drift with a second chip at the same temperature, or even (for precision equipment) controlling the chip's temperature in an oven. Consider these as "advanced" and don't go there unless you have to...

Comment: I had originally thought it might be the warming of the circuit and that it should stabalize after 30 minutes to an hour, but as it was still wondering after 60 minutes I figure it must be something else also acting on it.  Anyway, it's finals this week so I don't have time right now to trace out the cause but will look into all the suggestions once I'm done tests.